# docker domain/port mapping to localhost

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose and one of my containers makes requests to `domain.name.com:443` (cannot be changed) that is not accessible from the host. There is a tunnel on `localhost:542` that holds this endpoint on the host. Can I map this somehow in the docker compose or use some workarounds?

Kind of `domain.name.com:443:542` that requests from `domain.name.com:443` from the container arrive to `localhost:542`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an entry on container's `/etc/hosts` file mapping that domain to your host's IP address

```
docker run -it --add-host "parent.example.com:192.168.0.2" --network="host" --rm busybox
```

Test from container with:

```
/ # cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.0.2     parent.example.com

/ # wget -q http://parent.example.com:8000 -O -

response from parent.example.com:8000
```

In my case, I tested on the host running a minimal web server

```
 while true ; do { echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n"; echo "response from parent.example.com:8000" ; } | netcat -q 0 -l 8000 ;done
```

Your mapping should be `--add-host "domain.name.com:<your_ip_address>"`.
The ssh tunnel should be made on port 443, not 542.

Comment: Thank you. That does work. In the beginning I though that you suggest to modify Dockerfile to add entry to `/etc/hosts`. `add-host` does it in runtime, no changes to Dockerfile are required. For docker-sompose that would be `extra_hosts` option. Host network is not required, I use default bridge and bind it to `172.17.0.1`.